# Trying to get 10 tweets a day for last 30 days using snscrape

Tags: python, twitter

When i run this, it skips over i+1 days. What's going on here? I want i tweets from each of the last 30 days with this code.

```
for x in range(30):
    for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('ethereum exclude:retweets lang:en since:'+first_date+' until:'+second_date).get_items()):
        if i>3:
            break
        if x < 30:
            first_date = datetime.strptime(first_date, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(days=1)
            first_date = first_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            second_date = datetime.strptime(second_date, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(days=1)
            second_date = second_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        elif x==30:
            final_day() 
            break
        else:
            break
        run_the_tweets(tweet)
        x+=1
        i+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to manually increment either `i` nor `x` (which stands for the day index). The for loop will increment it for you already.

So just removing

```
x+=1
i+=1
```

should do the trick.